# Why does `endfloat` package reserve a whole page for each float when they are small enough to be put together?

Tags: floats, positioning, margins, wrapfigure, endfloat

I use `endfloat` package to stack all floats after the document has ended, but it seems that even if some floats are small enough to be put together in one page, `endfloat` will still place each one in a whole page. **How can I get** `endfloat` **to place as much floats as it could in one page?**

Another question. How can I increase the text body (i.e., reduce horizontal and vertical margins) in the final pages that will host the postponed floats?

I use `wrapfig` because with any suggested solutions, I do not want figures inside `wrapfigure` to be sent to the end of the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[nofiglist, notablist]{endfloat}
    \renewcommand{\figureplace}{\floatplace{figure}}
        \renewcommand{\tableplace}{\floatplace{table}}
        \renewcommand{\floatplace}[1]{
            \begin{center}
                \color{DodgerBlue3} \normalsize \textbf{
                [~\csname #1name\endcsname˜
                \csname thepost#1\endcsname~ is about here.~]
                        }
                \end{center}                
                                    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.35\linewidth} 

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

       \centering This is a circuit

    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{My Fig}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason for placing graphs and tables at the very end of the document is the same as for placing one table or one figure on a page: distributed work flow. In an old-time print shop, the people working on getting graphs and tables ready for typesetting were highly specialized. It made their work much easier if they had one and only one graph or table to work on at a time. BTW, if you're using the `endfloat` package, it's probably because you were told to do so, right? If so, let the print shop do its work the way it sees fit, and don't worry about the particulars of their work flow.

Comment: One page 8 (Section 7) of the manual it shows how to put more than one float per page.  Basically, the default `\efloatseparator` is `\clearpage`, so use something else.